# Responsive progress bar indicator with css arrow trick cross browser compatibility

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have found a preaty good solution to making a progress bar indicator here:

```
<ul class="progress">
   <li class="active"><a href="">Qualify</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Develop</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Propose</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Close</a></li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
ul.progress li.active {
  background-color: #dc9305;
}

ul.progress li {
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
  position:relative;
  text-indent:0.5em;
}
ul.progress li:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  right:100%;
  margin-right:0.4em;
  width:1.2em;
  padding-top:1.2em;;
  border:solid white;
  z-index:1;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  border-bottom:0;
  border-left:0;
  box-shadow:5px -5px 0 3px  #7e7e7e
}
ul.progress li.active:after {
  box-shadow:6px -6px 0 3px #dc9305;
}
ul.progress {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap
}

ul.progress li {
  display:inline-block;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  min-width: 130px;
  position: relative;  
  transition:min-width 0.5s;
}


ul.progress li a {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 6px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.progress li:hover {
  min-width:300px;
}
ul.progress li:before {
  content:'\2714'
}
ul.progress li.active:before,
ul.progress li.active ~ li:before {
  content:''
}
```

You can find the source here:
[enter link description here](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/FnKim/)

I made this code responsive and its working fine if you change display: block to display: tabel and table-cell for li elements.

My problem with CSS shadow arrow trick. Its broking on Safari and Mozilla. Have you got any idea to solve this?

Comment: try adding vendor prefixes for the relevant rules

Comment: This code was deficient:
`transform: rotate(45deg);`
`-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);`
`-moz-box-transform: rotate(45deg);`
Its preaty cool!

Comment: If you use modification above it will be ok under Safari also. Sorry, but I can't answer my question, but this was the solution...